# 'docker ps' and 'docker-compose ps' commands give different result

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

**docker ps** is giving me a different output compared to **docker-compose ps**.

For example

> docker ps

is not showing the same containers as

> docker-compose ps

and vice-versa.

What is the reason for this?

I was thinking *docker-compose* is working on top of *docker*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`docker ps` lists all running containers in docker engine. `docker-compose ps` lists containers related to images declared in `docker-compose file`.

The result of `docker-compose ps` is a subset of the result of `docker ps`.

Comment: *"The result of docker-compose ps is a subset of the result of docker ps."* It won't be the subset in all the cases. Let's say when the container is failed to run it will show in `docker-compose ps` but not in `docker ps`

Answer (score 1):

`docker ps` - lists all running containers in Docker engine.

`docker-compose ps` - lists containers for the given docker compose configuration. The result will depend on configuration and parameters passed to `docker-compose` command.

**Example**

Start the containers with the following command:

```
docker-compose -p prod up -d
```

*(`-p` in the command above defines the project name)*

Running `docker-compose ps` won't list containers since the project name parameters is not passed:

```
docker-compose ps

Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------
```

Running `docker-compose -p prod ps` will list all containers:

```
     Name                   Command               State                       Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dev_app_1        sh -c exec java ${JAVA_OPT ...   Up      0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9000/tcp
dev_database_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
dev_nginx_1      /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
dev_pgadmin_1    /entrypoint.sh                   Up      443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9100->80/tcp
```

The same goes if you define for example docker compose files with `-f` parameter.